# I need to know how to plot a 3D plane using MATLAB knowing its Hor. and Ver. extents?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, plane, extent

I need to know how to plot a 3D plane using MATLAB knowing its Horizontal and Vertical extents, Surface area, Center Point, and Dip angle and Dip Direction.

All I can find is how to generate an infinite 3D plane !!!

In my case, I know the horizontal and vertical extensions of the plane, and I know its surface of the bounding rectangle. So I want to write a script in MATLAB to plot this Finite plane?

Can you kindly advise?
Regards

Comment: Have you tried in [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538117/how-to-draw-the-3d-planes) ?

Comment: Alariva, thanks for your reply. So, do u mean this is not possible mathematically?

Comment: No, I mean that Math is a more specific forum for your purpose, and you will probably get a better/prompt answer.

Comment: Oh. I don't know how to do that. However, I found a way around though using Matlab. I still need to verify it. I can share it with you and u may provide me with your feed back! Do u want to give it a look?

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question. [Check out here](http://math.stackexchange.com/)